# Инициализация элементов в динамическом массиве по умолчанию и как её избежать

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, инициализация

Суть моего вопроса связана с тем, что при выделении динамического массива примитивных типов в C++ его значения по умолчанию инициализируются нулевыми, например:

```cpp
int* array = new int[size];
```

создаст динамический массив из `size` нулей.

Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Гарантирует ли стандарт C++ инициализацию элементов динамически выделенного массива нулями при использовании оператора `new[]` без явных инициализаторов?
2. Тратит ли программа в различных реализациях выделения динамического массива время на инициализацию элементов нулями?
3. Есть ли способ выделения динамического массива в C++, который позволяет избежать затрат времени на инициализацию, если мне важна максимальная производительность и я планирую немедленно перезаписать все элементы массива?

Comment: В массиве по стандарту мусор. Читать элемент нельзя пока вы не записали в него что-нибудь.

Comment: В некоторых рантаймах если вы выделите большой массив, он даже не будет отображен на память до момента первого обращения.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но по моему опыту получается, что там всегда нули. Видимо, какая-то специфичная реализация? Может быть, зависит от операционной системы и компилятора?

Comment: Вы в дебаге. А дебаг "помогает". И помогает двумя способами: может залить память кучи нулём (или другим значением), может залить выделяемый блок.

Comment: `#include <new> .. operator new` как аналог `malloc` не инициализирует объекты. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new Обыкновенный `new` - инициализирует.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, оператор `new` выделяет сырую память, но не размещает в ней объекты. В  С++ без размещения нельзя обращаться к элементам массива. Так что оператор `new` не поможет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я попробовал скомпилировать программу в релизе - и там всё так же массив заполнен нулями.

Comment: @AvidCoder, напишите хороший тест. Надо выделять и освобождать много массивов. Так что бы память в куче начала переиспользоваться. Тогда вы увидите мусор. Забыл добавить, что операционная система тоже "помогает": вы всегда получаете очищенные страницы памяти, чтобы нельзя случайно увидеть данных других процессов.

Comment: когда вы станете выставлять значения, то можно вызывать конструктор `new (адрес)(число)`, вместо простого присваивания, тогда уже по стандарту не придирёшся. @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: "и там всё так же массив заполнен нулями" - всё зависит от операционки. винда кажется сама чищет память нулями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В массиве по стандарту мусор. В конкретной реализации там могут оказаться нули потому что:

- нули могут там быть случайно, как побочный результат работы менеджера кучи или как старые данные;
- в отладочном режиме выделяемые блоки могут быть залиты нулями, в релизе такого быть не должно;
- в отладочном режиме сегмент памяти под кучу залит нулями;
- когда процесс получает память от операционной системы, страница залита нулями (защита данных).

Чтобы все эти причины не влияли, нужно собрать релиз и запустить код, который будет использовать память из кучи многократно. Например так:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int n = 0; ; ++n) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
        int *a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (a[i] != 0) {
                std::cout << "garbage\n";
                return 0;
            }
            a[i] = i;
        }
        delete[] a;
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp 
>
> $ ./a.out 
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> garbage
> ```

**P.S.** В этой программе есть неопределённое поведение. Так и должно быть - ищем мусор в неинициализованных данных.

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже написал свой тест, который показал, что после первой инициализации в массиве присутствуют мусорные значения.

Comment: В общем, понятно, что лишнее время на инициализацию не тратится. И это хорошо. Моей ошибкой было предположить, что раз при первом создании массива он забит нулями, то то же будет и при последующих созданиях.